# IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value when injecting property to boolean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In Spring Boot I attempt to inject a boolean value to an instance variable from an enviroment property which is set (`enabled=true`).

```
@Value("${enabled}")
private boolean enabled;
```

However Spring cannot resolve this for some reason and reports:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${enabled}]
```

It seems like it does not replace expression `${enabled}` with the property value.

What needs to be set ? Why doesn't work this by default ?

Comment: well i added your case to my project and it works. Is it the only @Value not mapped?

Comment: Does this variable belong to managed bean and component scan is enabled or this bean is specified in configuration? It'll be usefull, if you show us whole Bean class and some configurations

Comment: The problem must be somehow related to `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. I debugged the Spring code and simply Spring does not evaluated `${enabled}`.

Comment: Can you try with wrapper class Boolean instead of primitive ?

Comment: Yes, you have to declare a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer static bean in your configuration, to make it works, that's why it's hard to tell something without any configuration example

Answer (score 2):

For Spring-Boot you can find good reference here:
http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

For given **someprops.properites** file:

```
somevalue:true
```

Here is **FAILING** version:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource( "/someprops.properties" )
public class FailingNg {

    @Configuration
    public static class Config {
    }

    @Value("${somevalue}")
    private Boolean somevalue;

    // Fails with context initializatoin java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${somevalue}]
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("somevalue: " + somevalue);
    }
}
```

Here is **WORKING** version:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class WorkingOk {

    @Configuration
    public static class Config {
        @Bean
        public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
            PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
            Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[] { 
                    new ClassPathResource( "someprops.properties" )
            };
            ppc.setLocations( resources );
            ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders( true );
            return ppc;
        }
    }

    @Value("${somevalue}")
    private Boolean somevalue;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("somevalue: " + somevalue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you are likely missing a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean definition. Here's an example of how to configure that within Java:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_FILENAME = "app.properties"; // Change as needed.    

   /**
     * This instance is necessary for Spring to load up the property file and allow access to
     * it through the @Value(${propertyName}) annotation. Also note that this bean must be static
     * in order to work properly with current Spring behavior.
     */
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[] { new ClassPathResource(PROPERTY_FILENAME) };
        pspc.setLocations(resources);
        pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return pspc;
    }
}
```